# Using Structs to hold all my variables in a C game?

Tags: c, function, variables, struct

I am currently getting into some more advanced C programming with SDL and I've been having a lot of trouble with functions and overall program structure.

My main problem is that games require a lot of variables that most functions need to access and manipulate. I don't want to create a bunch of global variables, but I also don't want to be passing around every single relevant variable each time I access a function.

To solve this, I created a Game struct at the top of the program. This struct holds all of the game variables that needs to be passed around like textures and locations. I declare an instance of that struct at the beginning of my main function, initialize all the variables inside, and then proceed to pass the struct instance around to different functions.

My question is: is this a good solution? Perhaps there is a better, more conventional way to deal with this; if so, please explain.

This is more of a theoretical question and has no grounding in any specific code that I can show you.

Comment: Perhaps this might be best asked on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com if there's no code to show.

Comment: It's slightly better than having all the variables be global - now for example you could run two games in the same process! - but not by much. You're basically transitioning from no real program structure at all to the [god object anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

The observations you're making are a good start though. The basic problem you have is visibility; If all of your code can touch all of your state all the time, you get a giant mess. Making sure that your code can access the things it needs to, and _only_ those is a fairly difficult engineering challenge.

Comment: It's a reasonable approach.  Depending on circumstances, the primary alternative is sets of functions that manage related sets of game resources, which you can call to find or change values.  It has merits in that less code needs recompiling if you change one of the lower-level dependent modules.  How much of a problem that is depends on how much information you embed directly in your main `Game` structure vs how much is hidden behind opaque pointers in the structure.  This controls to some extent the number of times you'll have to recompile everything vs only the parts that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of better... but it's an opinion thing. First, It looks nicer. Second, if you're smart, you can dump the entire game structure to a file for later loading. (I don't know how, but I know it can be done)

Also, you should declare the struct at the top level:

```
/* main.c */

typedef struct{
    int health;
    int xp_level;
} game_t;

game_t GAME;

void takeHit(){
    printf("The monster hits you!\n")
    GAME.helath--;
}

main(){
    GAME.health = 42;
    GAME.xp_level = 0;
    printf("Health: %d | Level: %d\n",GAME.health,GAME.xp_level);
    takeHit();
    printf("Health: %d | Level: %d\n",GAME.health,GAME.xp_level);
}
```

---

```
$ make main
$ ./main
Health: 42 | Level: 0
The monster hits you!
Health: 41 | Level: 0
```

Hence any functions you write just have acess to the struct without needing to pass it.

You could also use the Ularn approach:

```
/* Character.h */

#define NUMBER_ATTRIBUTES 4

#define HP 0    
#define STR 1
#define INT 2
#define WIS 3
/* etc... */

int c[NUMBER_ATTRIBUTES];
```

Comment: but isn't that just the same as declaring a bunch of global variables? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yeah, but it's a little nicer.